# Select most recent record for each member

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Using T-SQL I have 2 tables one which lists all members(recEntrants). The second table(recEntrantStatus) contains status update for each member. At present I have the following SQL to retrieve all updates for all members.

```
SELECT EN.Id, EN.artistName, GR.genre, ES.lastModifiedOn, EN.voteStatus, 
ES.notified
FROM recEntrantStatus AS ES
JOIN recEntrants AS EN
ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
JOIN recGenre AS GR
ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
AND ES.judgeId = @judgeId
AND ES.roundId > 0
ORDER BY ES.voted DESC, ES.roundId, EN.Id
```

NEW REQUIREMENTS ADDED BELOW:

```
SELECT EN.Id, EN.artistName, GR.genre, ES.lastModifiedOn, EN.voteStatus, 
ES.notified
FROM recEntrantStatus AS ES
LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
WHERE ES.roundId = 2
```

However, what I need to achieve is to just pull the most recent status update/record for each member.

P.s. I have a modifiedDate column on recEntrantStatus

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if there's a tie for lastModifiedOn?

Comment: To be honest, the best way to get the most recent would be based on the Id key for a given members status updates. But good point worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `row_number()`  *over* `(partition by ES.entrantId order by ES.lastModifiedOn desc)`. Please add Order by column list to the sub query if you still need to use the same order. Also if you need to select records who has `NO status records` then use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT EN.Id, EN.artistName, GR.genre, ES.lastModifiedOn, EN.voteStatus, 
       ES.notified,
       row_number() over (partition by ES.entrantId order by ES.lastModifiedOn desc) rn 
    FROM recEntrantStatus AS ES
    JOIN recEntrants AS EN
        ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id JOIN recGenre AS GR
        ON EN.genreId = GR.Id AND ES.judgeId = @judgeId AND ES.roundId > 0
) A
WHERE A.rn = 1
--ORDER BY A.voted DESC, A.roundId, A.Id
```

**EDIT** (as per OP edit):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ES.entrantId Id, EN.artistName, GR.genre, ES.lastModifiedOn, EN.voteStatus, 
       ES.notified,
       row_number() over (partition by ES.entrantId order by ES.lastModifiedOn desc) rn 
    FROM recEntrantStatus AS ES
    LEFT JOIN recEntrants AS EN
        ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id LEFT JOIN recGenre AS GR
        ON EN.genreId = GR.Id 
    --AND ES.judgeId = @judgeId 
    WHERE ES.roundId = 2
) A
WHERE A.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Kaf. That works perfectly. I appreciate the additional comments about Left Join and order by. Ive got both aspects covered, but always appreciate the extra effort in covering all the bases!!

Comment: I have a slight adaptation of the above where I have a 'WHERE' clause. Ive updated the original SELECT statement in my OP above. Could you possibly, rework your answer to incorporate this new where clause as I cant work out where to place it. Thanks.

Comment: Since ES is left most table, you can replace `AND ES.roundId > 0` of my answer with `WHERE ES.roundId = 2` and of course keep `LEFT JOINS` as per your new query. Check out, I have updated.

Comment: Thanks Kaf! I actually worked it out due to your clear answer first time around. Your updated response has just confirmed that I had got it right. So massive thanks to you mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without adding a ModifiedDate column which, will contain the date and time of modification of that column. Then you can do this:

`select * from tableA where whatever='whatever' order by ModifiedDate desc`.

Also, you might want to look into insert/update triggers which will modify this column each time an update or insert happen.

However, if you just want the first entry, you need `TOP()`

Comment: I do actually have the modifiedDate column and triggers in place to update them. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH MostRecent
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY entrantId ORDER BY lastModifiedOn DESC) RN,
        entrantId,
        judgeId,
        roundId,
        voted 
    FROM recEntrantStatus
)
SELECT
    EN.Id,
    EN.artistName,
    GR.genre,
    ES.lastModifiedOn,
    EN.voteStatus, 
    ES.notified
FROM MostRecent AS ES
    JOIN recEntrants AS EN
ON ES.entrantId = EN.Id
    JOIN recGenre AS GR
ON EN.genreId = GR.Id
   AND ES.judgeId = @judgeId
   AND ES.roundId > 0
WHERE ES.RN = 1
ORDER BY ES.voted DESC, ES.roundId, EN.Id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that throws some complaint about a couple of column names not being valid. So if I remove ';WITH MostRecent AS' it then runs but doesnt return anything like the expected results.